# UPDATE statement in PHP needs know if new file is selected or not

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a client edit form that successfully uploads an image to my website. When I uploaded a file using the FILE field, it then will save it to my mysql database.

The problem is, if I save the client record again, if there is nothing in the FILE field, it will overwrite the existing record with blank entry. If nothing new gets uploaded, I would like it to NOT overwrite what was already saved.

The code below should explain better. I'm guessing the UPDATE shouldn't proceed with **coupon_img='$file'** when no new file has been chosen to upload?

```
    <?php 
 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name']; 
 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size']; 
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
 $folder="coupons/"; 
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$category = $_POST['category']; 
$package = $_POST['package']; 
$client_name = $_POST['client_name']; 
$client_img = $_POST['client_img']; 
$deal = $_POST['deal']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$yelp = $_POST['yelp']; 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$latlong = $_POST['latlong']; 


 move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file); 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET id='$id', category='$category', coupon_img='$file', package='$package', client_name='$client_name', client_img='$client_img', deal='$deal', phone='$phone', yelp='$yelp', address='$address', latlong='$latlong' WHERE id='$id'"; 
$result_edit=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql); 

// if successfully updated.  
if($result_edit){ 
header("Location: edit/edit.php"); 
} 

else { 
echo "ERROR"; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this...

```
if($_FILES['file']['name'] == "") {
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET id='$id', category='$category', package='$package', client_name='$client_name', client_img='$client_img', deal='$deal', phone='$phone', yelp='$yelp', address='$address', latlong='$latlong' WHERE id='$id'"; 
 } else {
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET id='$id', category='$category', coupon_img='$file', package='$package', client_name='$client_name', client_img='$client_img', deal='$deal', phone='$phone', yelp='$yelp', address='$address', latlong='$latlong' WHERE id='$id'";  
 }
```